# Adding Spaces in select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down select menu that is pulling values from the database. Since they are pulling from the database the text looked squished like TitleIsAvalible. I can go ahead and select these values and add the space via console, but they're not changing on the screen.

I'm sure this is something simple I'm forgetting, but I just can figure it out.

My select looks like this

```
<p>
   <select class="form-control js_create">
     <option value="">Edit an existing table</option>
     <option value="16">AuthenticationOperations</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

but I would like that option to read Authentication Operations instead.

I have tried something like this

```
$('.js_create option').text().replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are they stored without spaces in your database? How are you generating the HTML for the options?

Comment: Yes they are stored without the spaces, but I wish to display it with spaces to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a function to `text()` which does the manipulation of the current value. Try this:

```
$('.js_create option').text(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dh6q8tL3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the value into `text` again

like bellow

```
$('.js_create option').each(function(){
    var formattedText = $(this).text().replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
    $(this).text(formattedText);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dh6q8tL3/1/)

Comment: This will make all options have the same value.